# Where did I make a mistake in the sign-up form?

Tags: html, css

```css
.login-page {
  width: 360px;
  padding: 10% 0 0;
  margin: auto;
}

.form {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: black;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}

.form input {
  outline: none;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  width: 100%;
  border: 0;
  margin: 0 0 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.form button {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  outline: 0;
  background: orange;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.form button:hover,
.form button:active {
  background: green;
  border: none;
}

.form .zaten {
  margin: 15px 0 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.form .zaten a {
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.register-form {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
      <form class="register-form">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Name Surname">
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
        <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
        <input type="tel-no" placeholder="Telephone Number">
        <button type="button">Register</button>
        <p class="zaten"> Already have a account? <a href="#"> Login </p>
   </form>
   <form class="login-form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email or Phone Number">
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
     <button type="button">Login</button>
     <p class="zaten"> Not registered yet? <a href="#"> Register </p>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script>
  $('.zaten a').click(function()
  {
   $('form').animate({height:"toggle",opacity:"toggle"}, "slow");
  });
 </script>
</body>
```

When I look at how my site looks, I saw `<p class="zaten"> Not registered yet? <a href="#"> Register </p>` place as whole clickable orange text. How can I change the color and make it text, not link. 
If you have difficulty understanding pardon me, English is not my native language. If you need more informaiton, ask freely.

Comment: if you don't want it as a link then remove the anchor tag (also you haven't closed either of your anchors, the first of which is causing the second part to be classed as clickable - if you only want the word login to be clickable, then close the anchor after the word).  Voting to clsoe as typo

Comment: lol I didn't notice I haven't closed anchors thank you, problem solved.

Comment: @Wardon98 You can mark this question as answered by selecting one of the answers as "best answer" :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"</a>"`missing closing tag...
`<p class="zaten"> Not registered yet? <a href="#"> Register </a> </p>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $('.zaten a').click(function()
    {
        $('form').animate({height:"toggle",opacity:"toggle"}, "slow");
    });
```

```css
.login-page {
width:360px;
padding: 10% 0 0;
margin: auto;} .form {
position:relative;
z-index: 1;
background-color:black;
max-width: 360px;
margin: 0 auto 100px;
padding:45px;
text-align:center;} .form input {
outline:none;
background:#f2f2f2;
width:100%;
border: 0;
margin: 0 0 15px;
padding:15px;
box-sizing: border-box;
font-size:14px;} .form button {
text-transform: capitalize;
outline: 0;
background: orange;
width: 100%;
border: none;
padding: 15px;
font-size: 14px;
color:white;
cursor: pointer;} .form button:hover,.form button:active {
background: green;
border:none;} .form .zaten {
margin:15px 0 0;
color:white;
font-size:12px;} .form .zaten a {
color: orange;
text-decoration: none;} .register-form {display:none;}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
        <form class="register-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name Surname">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="tel-no" placeholder="Telephone Number">
                <button type="button">Register</button>
                <p class="zaten"> Already have a account? <a href="#"> Login</a> </p>
        </form>
        <form class="login-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email or Phone Number">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
                <button type="button">Login</button>
                <p class="zaten"> Not registered yet? <a href="#"> Register </a></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that you have forgotten to close a tag and that lead to unexcpted

```
<div class="login-page">
    <div class="form">
        <form class="register-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name Surname">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="tel-no" placeholder="Telephone Number">
                <button type="button">Register</button>
                <p class="zaten"> Already have a account? <a href="#" class="btn"> Login </a></p>
        </form>
        <form class="login-form">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email or Phone Number">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
                <button type="button">Login</button>
                <p class="zaten"> Not registered yet? <a href="#" class="btn"> Register </a></p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```